# Django Python Script

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I've been sifting through the documention but I don't feel like I'm getting a clear answer.  Is it possible to run something python-like

```
if company_name.startswith(('A')):
enter code here
```

from within a Django site or app?  How would I go about it?

Currently the code I use is

```
            {% for TblCompanies in object_list %}
              <tr class="customer-table">
                <td>{{ TblCompanies.company_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ TblCompanies.company_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ TblCompanies.contact_phone }}</td>
                <td>{{ TblCompanies.billing_address }}</td>
                <td>{{ TblCompanies.contact_e_mail }}</td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

but our customer database is too large and it's a burden to have to go through the list to find a customer.  I want to instead sort it alphabetically using urls like http://path/to/customer_list/A

Comment: Do you want to have that function in a template? Why don't you put it in the view?

Comment: You're right, I should have it in a view.  I'm slowly transitioning my structure into view oriented objects but I'm not as fluid in python programming just yet :)

Comment: Django Templates have very limited features. I think you don't have an option of adding functions in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`slice` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#slice), you can get a substring; then compare the substring with the `'A'`:

```
{% for TblCompanies in object_list %}
  {% if TblCompanies.company_name|slice:':1' == 'A' %}
  <tr class="customer-table">
    <td>{{ TblCompanies.company_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ TblCompanies.company_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ TblCompanies.contact_phone }}</td>
    <td>{{ TblCompanies.billing_address }}</td>
    <td>{{ TblCompanies.contact_e_mail }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

As @Matthias commented, it would be better to pass filtered `object_list` in view. Assuming `object_list` is a queryset object:

```
object_list = object_list.filter(company_name__startswith='A')
```

---

### Sorintg

Sort the `object_list` before passing it to the template:

```
page = requests.REQUEST.get('page', 'A')  # or Get from view parameter
                                          #    depending on url conf.
object_list = (object_list.filter(company_name__startswith=page)
                          .order_by('company_name'))
```

**UPDATE**

NOTE: Change `app` with actual app name.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^/path/to/site/customers/(?P<page>[A-Z])$', 'app.views.list_customers')
```

app/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def list_compnaies(request, page):
    object_list = (Customer.objects.filter(company_name__startswith=page)
                           .order_by('company_name'))
    return render(request, 'customers/list.html', {
        'object_list': object_list,
    })
```

customers/list.html

```
{# Link to A .. Z customer pages %}
{% for page in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' %}
<a href="/path/to/site/customers/{{ page }}">{{ page }}</a>
{# Use {% url ... %} once you learn the url tag if possible to reduce duplicated hard-coded url #}
{% endif %}

{% for TblCompanies in object_list %}
<tr class="customer-table">
    <td>{{ TblCompanies.company_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ TblCompanies.company_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ TblCompanies.contact_phone }}</td>
    <td>{{ TblCompanies.billing_address }}</td>
    <td>{{ TblCompanies.contact_e_mail }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That means 27 different pages.  Guess I should turn this into a form.

Comment: @Addohm, I don't get it? Didn't you want to `if` functionality in the template?

Comment: Doesn't have to be.  Just now had the thought it would be more efficient to pass it through a form.  You guys, being the proficient ones, would know better :)

Comment: I am sorting the objects in the urls.py  `url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=TblCompanies.objects.all().order_by("company_name"), template_name="customers/list.html")),`  I'll obviously still want to order it, but I need it alphabetical as well.  What are your thoughts.  Should I put it in a form or run with what you've given me already?

Comment: @Addohm, By using `.order_b‌​y("company_name")`, you will get alphabetically sorted one.

Comment: My original plan was to have a CSS Pagination at the top and the user clicks a letter.

Comment: Yes, as I said, I get the entire ordered list now but it's just too long.

Comment: @Addohm, How about get parameter like `?page=A` (or capture the page in the url: `^page/(\P<page>\d+)/?$`)and filter `object_list` in the view as shown in the answer?

Comment: That's beyond me :-(

Comment: @Addohm, I updated the answer to show example. I'm going to sleep. If you have more question, add comment. I will answer 9~10 hours later.

Comment: by this you're saying to use a form with the get method right?  I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with object_list in views.  Not enough experience shows :-(

Comment: you're great.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Also, if all you want is to display a list of many entries N entries at a time, you could look into Django built-in pagination support
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/

Comment: Thanks.  Not exactly what I'm looking to do.  Besides that, I'm learning a great deal with @falsetru !

Comment: @falsetru  Would it be too much to ask for a top to bottom example?  I feel like I'm getting close but keep getting mixed up on what to put where.  The documentation clearly defines what to put in urls.py but not views.py and I can't get it to mesh with what you provided.  What I'm expecting at this point is a URL like http://path/to/site/customers/A/ would list all the customers starting with 'A'.

Comment: @Addohm, I added url/view/template code. Check it out.

Comment: Wow, you're a great help.  I can't wait to play with this!  Will try to understand this better tomorrow when I can add it.

Comment: Immediate and thoughtless implimentation resulted in `view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().` :P  I assume you've done everything in the app's urls.py and apps.py?

Comment: I unbroke it, but it's not working quite yet.  Need to sleep :)  Thanks so much for lending me your time!

Comment: @Addohm, I marked the codes with filenames. You need to adjust `app` with your actual app name.

Comment: After some work I got this working.  Thanks so much.  Side question: is it standard practice to use the root urls.py for everything?  Seems easier but several of the tutorials and the Django docs use the app/urls.py practice.

Comment: @Addohm, No, it's not, AFAIK.